# How to update files in Google Cloud Storage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've recently built a static website with a bucket via the Google Cloud Storage. The bucket includes a JSON file "data.json" which includes all the data required for the website. I knew how to use JavaScript to fetch the JSON file, just simply

```
fetch("data.json")
```

But I'll need to update the content in the JSON file and overwrite the file, what should I do then, any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked out the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs)?

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Storage Client library is not available for JavaScript. But there is the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1?hl=en_US) you could access whith JavaScript.

You have to keep in mind that this would be easy to attack. So there has to be some kind of security.

I would recommend moving your website into a Python Flask App and to use Google Cloud Run. It is really cheap, really simple and you have a native implementation for Cloud Storage.